# Configure Security Manager on Tomcat7

Tags: security, tomcat

Trying to configure Security Manager for Tomcat 7. We are running Java 1.8.0_51 on a 64 bit Windows 2008 server and run Tomcat as a service. I've added the following lines as Java Options:

```
-Djava.security.manager
-Djava.security.policy=D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat7.0\conf\catalina.policy
```

The security policy file is the default file and has not been modified. After adding the lines I can no longer start Tomcat. I get the following error messages:

```
2015-10-07 08:58:31 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized properties: reading security properties file: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\security\java.security jar: beginEntry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF jar: done with meta! jar: nothing to verify! scl: getPermissions ProtectionDomain  (file:/D:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat7.0/bin/tomcat-juli.jar <no signer certificates>)  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44  <no principals>  java.security.Permissions@28d93b30 (  ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM")  ("java.io.FilePermission" "\D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat7.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" "read") ) scl:  policy: reading file:/D:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat7.0/conf/catalina.policy     [Policy Parser]: sun.security.util.PropertyExpander$ExpandException: unable to expand property catalina.home    [Policy Parser]: sun.security.util.PropertyExpander$ExpandException: unable to expand property catalina.base
```

I also see errors like the following:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null KeyStore name

If I remove the new config lines all is well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your file path has spaces in it, did you quote it ?

Comment: The policy file is found and is being parsed. I tested this by adding a bad value to the policy file and then seeing that value error out in one of the Tomcat log files.

Comment: Ok, did you also try adding catalina.home and catalina.base system properties via -D ?

Comment: I have CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE operating system environment variables. Are those the same? if not, should I have to manually set those values?

Comment: No it's not the same (unless there's something in the startup script that sets the properties from the environment variables), try setting those two system properties in the java options as well - the error message seems to indicate they are missing

Comment: Added the two system properties to the JVM options and now Tomcat starts!
However, my Remedy application does not. I am getting permission errors which prevents the application from loading. The application is stored in another folder (not webapps) and there is a file in /conf/catalina/localhost/arsys.xml that instructs Tomcat to load the application. I have tried adding:
        permission java.io.FilePermission "file:${remedy.home}\ARSystem\midtier\*", "read,write";

in the policy file but cannot get beyond the error.

Comment: You could try changing the appBase entry for the host node in server.xml to point at the base of the directory with the webapp you want to install.